# Implement interface with Disposable Pattern

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, visual-studio-2015

Note: This is a Visual Studio 2015 feature only, as far as I know...

How can I edit the **Implement interface with Disposable Pattern** option?

[image: Implement Interface with Disposable Pattern]

This is NOT a question on how to Implement the Dispose Pattern and its variations, but how to edit the option "Implement interface with Disposable Pattern"

I would like to remove some comments and add some code on the Disposable Pattern, but I want it to be saved and every time I click "**Implement interface with Disposable Pattern**", it implements my code, not the default one.
Also I would like to create my own "**Implement interface with MyOwn Pattern**" option
and target it to a interface (not limited to IDisposable)

I have tried to do it with **code snippet**, but it doesn't work, I **can't** create or edit a "Implement interface with XXX" option.

It seems that this option is kind of "built in", but it seems like a "extensible" option...

Comment: I believe this is a feature of the Roslyn engine called Analysers and Code Fixes. I tried to find a straight forward walkthrough but I think it's a fairly complex thing to implement. Have a look here for some details: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/How-To-Write-a-C%23-Analyzer-and-Code-Fix

Comment: You may want to check this: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/9760