# Is it possible to create custom implementation of interface with pattern?

Tags: c#, .net, interface

I found that for implementation of IDisposable interface Visual Studio 2019 suggests two possible fixes:

[image]

Is it possible to create a custom interface with an option to implement with some pattern?

If it's possible then how to do it?

The only somehow related post I found is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358969/implement-interface-with-disposable-pattern).